# Проблемы с JsonObject

Tags: json, qt

У меня  есть 2 функции: serialise и deserialise, я   в  юнит тесте  хочу проверить  правильно ли они работают. Но  тут  ошибки повыскакивали. и не понимаю что я  не так передаю Нужна ваша помощь
Тест:

```
  void UnitTests::testOne()
  {
      Task task1;
      task1.setQuestion("Вопрос");
      task1.setAnswer("Ответ");
      task1.setNumPoints(3);


      auto jsonObject = Archiver::serialise(&task1);
      Task  task2 = Archiver::deserialise(&jsonObject);
      areEqual(task1, task2);
  }
```

Но кампилятор кричит  на эти две строчки

```
  Task  task2 = Archiver::deserialise(&jsonObject);
  areEqual(task1, task2);
```

Ошибки

```
1)error: C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<Component,std::default_delete<_Ty>> Archiver::deserialise(const QJsonObject &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject,std::default_delete<_Ty>> *' to 'const QJsonObject &'
```

std::unique_ptr Archiver::deserialise(const QJsonObject &jsonData)

```
 2)  error: C3861: 'areEqual': identifier not found
```

но я функцию  areEqual создал в  юнит тесте.

UPD:

```
 class UnitTests : public QObject
 {
   Q_OBJECT

   public:
   UnitTests();

  private Q_SLOTS:
   void testOne();
   void testSecond();
   bool areEqual(const Component* comp1, const Component* comp2);
 };
 void UnitTests::testOne()
 {}
 void UnitTests::testSecond()
 {}

 bool areEqual(const Component* comp1, const Component* comp2)
 {}
 QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN(UnitTests)

 #include "UnitTests.moc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция `Archiver::deserialise` (или это бустовая?) на вход хочет `const QJsonObject &jsonData`, а Вы пытаетесь ей всунуть `sdt::unique_ptr<QJsonObject>`. Поэтому, скорее всего нужно сделать просто разыменование

```
Task  task2 = Archiver::deserialise(*jsonObject);
```

Но так как тип Task я только угадал, проверить решение не могу.

По второй ошибке. Вы так и не сказали, где именно объявлена функция areEqual. И компилятор её не видит (и я также не знаю, где она). Но у QJsonObject есть перегруженный `operator==`, поэтому, можно сравнивать напрямую. И написать где то так

```
QVERIFY(task1 == task2);
```

Comment: написал как вы сказали 1) ошибка  error: C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::unique_ptr<Component,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'Task' снова  не может сконвертировать

Comment: 2)  в UnitTests у меня идет так: void UnitTests::testOne()
{}  после нее идет функция bool areEqual(const Component* comp1, const Component* comp2)
{} и не понятно почему  ее не видет

Comment: 1) я так написал и прокатило : std::unique_ptr<Component>  task2 = Archiver::deserialise(*jsonObject);

Comment: 2) уже функции увидело,  но  другая ошибка: error: C2664: 'bool UnitTests::areEqual(const Component *,const Component *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Task' to 'const Component *'

Comment: похоже у Вас проблема с типами. То task, то component. Делайте простой пример, который воспроизведет проблему и можно будет что то думать.

Comment: Task унаследуется  от component

Comment: У меня  есть Test, Task которые унаследуюются  от Component

Comment: в данном случаи я  делаю  проверку с Task

Comment: Так  без ошибок: std::unique_ptr<Component> task2 = Archiver::deserialise(*jsonObject);
    areEqual(&task1, task2.get());

Comment: Но  есть  оишбка не понятная: UnitTests.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: bool __cdecl UnitTests::areEqual(class Component const *,class Component const *)" (?areEqual@UnitTests@@AEAA_NPEBVComponent@@0@Z) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl UnitTests::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@UnitTests@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)

Comment: это ошибка линковки. То есть, сам заголовок функции описан, а вот реализация линковщиком не найдена. Может быть cpp файл не добавлен к билду

Comment: я  написал в UPD свой клас UnitTest.cpp